# “Natural” finite measure over continuous probability densities over the interval [0,a]

Tags: probability, measure-theory, density-function

I wonder whether there is a "natural" finite measure μ
(such as the Lebesgue-Measure on R∩[0,a]) over the space of all continous probability density functions on [0,a]

Comment: What do you mean by "natural"?  There is certainly no obvious choice.

Comment: I'd think that if there was a "natural" choice, that'd be the one that would be taught most of the time, no? The fact that there isn't such a choice taught should tell you something.